# Specify the name that will be displayed with the To: email address

Tags: gmail

I want to write an email message containing a note to contact Fred Bloggs for more information. Fred's email address is fredbloggs@gmail.com.

If I follow the normal mechanism to include a link - click "insert link"; select the email radiobutton and enter fredbloggs@gmail.com as the address to link to - then when the recipient clicks on the link, the empty email message displays the To: address as "Fredbloggs", at least that's what it does if the recipient is using gmail via the web interface.

I'd like the address to be shown as "Fred Bloggs", but the default gmail web interface won't let me specify the address as either
"<Fred Bloggs> fredbloggs@gmail.com"
or
"Fred Bloggs <fredbloggs@gmail.com>".
It says both addresses are invalid.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

If I could specify a default subject line as well, that would be awesome.